# C++ parse sub-string to integer

Tags: c++, performance, string-parsing

I need a `strtol` function that would allow me specify bounds in which the string will be parsed. For example

```
char * number = "123456789";
std::cout << my_strtol(number, 1, 3);
```

Should print "234".

---

Using some pointer arithmetic I could get pretty close:

```
int32_t my_strtol(const char* str, int from_char, int to_char, int base = 10)
{
  char *end;
  auto res = strtol(str + from_char, &end, base);
  auto extra_digits = end - str - (to_char + 1);
  if(extra_digits > 0) res /= pow(10, extra_digits); 
  return res;
}
```

this however it fails if the string is greater than `LONG_MAX` (regardless the value of said part). For example input for `"1234567890123456789"` the call `str_to_l(number, 1, 3)` would fail and return 0. Moreover it uses unnecessary `pow` – the performance is crucial.

**Edit:** I would like to avoid constructing new strings or string streams, because I will be extracting multiple  integers from same buffer and even more importantly I will be *literally* performing tens thousands of these calls.

---

For those who are interested in (casual)profiling results of suggested solutions:

```
//put temp null character at end
int32_t my_strtol1(char* str, int from_char, int to_char, int base = 10)
{
    char tmp = str[to_char];
    str[to_char] = '\0';
    auto res = strtol(str + from_char, nullptr, base);
    str[to_char] = tmp;
    return res;
}

//use substr()
int32_t my_strtol2(const std::string& str,
    const std::string::size_type from_char,
    const std::string::size_type to_char,
    int base = 10) {
    return std::stol(str.substr(from_char, to_char - from_char + 1));
}

//using boost
int32_t my_strtol3(char* str, int from_char, int to_char) {
    return boost::lexical_cast<int>(str + from_char, to_char - from_char + 1);
}

//parse characters one by one
int32_t my_strtol4(const char* str, int from_char, int to_char)
{
    int32_t res = 0;
    for (int i = from_char; i < to_char; i++)
    {
        char ch = str[i];
        ch -= '0';
        if (ch > 10 || ch < 0) return 0;
        res *= 10;
        res += ch;
    }
    return res;
}
```

The output (measured by `clock_t`) on my machine was:

```
Manipulating null character with 100000 iterations took 0.114s
Using substr() with 100000 iterations took 0.62s
Using boost::lexical_cast<T>() with 100000 iterations took 0.231s
Parsing character one by one with 100000 iterations took 0.083s
```

Comment: `std::stol` is the C++11 version of C's `strtol`.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? What steps did you take? What do you expect the call to strtol to do? Hint: It's going to try to convert from the from_char until it sees a null terminator. Try [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead of `char *`, and use [`std::stol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) on a [`.substr()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr).

Comment: @MatsPetersson thanks for comment, but it is not important whether the input is c-style null terminated string or std::string (I can choose what char buffer type to use).

Comment: Actually, it _is_ important whether it is null-terminated or not. [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) will convert until it reaches a non-digit character or a null terminator. This is why you're getting issues with values greater than `LONG_MAX`.

Comment: something like `std::string numstr = number;  return std::stol(number.substr(from_char, to_char-from_char));`

Comment: You don't need to construct a new `std::string`, declare a local `char` buffer large enough to hold all the digits of a `long` and copy parts of your input string to it. Then pass this buffer to `strtol`

Comment: @Andrew well... thanks for pointing that out - I wasnt aware of it. However it will still fail to return correct value - it will throw `std::out_of_range` exception instead.

Comment: @wondra I've written up three approaches: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e551aca357385ebc are any of these suitable?

Comment: I meant I wasn't aware that there is `std::stol`. The input string was correct c-style null terminated string that was as whole out of range but not out of range as needed part.

Comment: @Andrew I like your 2nd approach, I am only concerned whether it is not a bad practice? If it is not, I think it is the solution.

Comment: @wondra it's not the best. You're manually terminating strings all over the place. It also requires quite a bit of checking that I didn't implement (e.g. to make sure all of the indices, ranges etc. fall within the original string's array). Working with `std::string` and its member functions, along with `std::stol` is a much safer approach. I'd try that, profile your application, and only when you know that the string constructor is taking an unacceptable amount of time, would you move to the other approaches.

Comment: @Andrew good to know. Because I have some guarantees about my inputs and I am loading actually parsing output of pure C library to my C++ code I think I can afford to go with 2nd solution. I also note the 1st solution should be preferred within my application. I think you can post the code (including the comments) as answer.

Comment: There's a better answer already from @MatsPetersson. If you don't need to deal with bases other than 10, simply remove the extra stuff that deals with those from Mats' answer, and add error checking as appropriate for your inputs.

Comment: I wonder what `lexical_cast` does for those extra 3x time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have *Boost*, it can be done as a one-liner using [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/examples.html#boost_lexical_cast.examples.converting_part_of_the_string), which has an overload that takes a `char` pointer and a length as arguments. From all I know, this is optimized (specialized) to operate directly on the input string with no copies or memory allocations performed and no streams involved.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

int
main()
{
  const auto text = "123456789";
  const auto number = boost::lexical_cast<int>(text + 1, 3);
  std::cout << number << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
234
```

I know I have originally learned this from another answer to  a very similar question some time ago but I'm failing to find it again so I'll replicate it here.

Comment: Profiling the results shows this solution is elegant, safe and reasonably fast, I am picking this as solution because of simplicity all-around results.

Answer (score 4):

So, if you don't need super portability (support for thai, chinese and arabic numbers, for example):

```
int32_t my_strtol(const char* str, int from_char, int to_char, int base = 10)
{
   int32_t res = 0; 
   for(int i = from_char; i < to_char; i++)
   {
      char ch = str[i];
      if (ch > '9' && base > 10)
      {
         ch &= ~32;    /* Make it upper case */
         ch -= 'A' + 10;
      }
      else 
      {
          ch -= '0';
      }
      if (ch > base || ch < 0)   ... do some error handling ... 
      res *= base;
      res += ch;
   }
   return res;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for misleading example and not-mentioning it - I expect only ASCII string input with 10 base. I only wrote my tested example more generic because it did not complicate the code.

Comment: @wondra it is easy enough to adapt Mats' solution. Simply multiply by 10 instead of by `base`, and remove the handling for non-digit characters. You should still do some range checking on the string indices, of course.

Comment: The only thing that could be added is a data type for `res`